# Can I choose rude names for my Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

In the older Pokémon games my brother and I always tried to come up with the most weird Pokémon-names. For example we chose something like "poo-toilet". Will others be able to see them and can you get in trouble if you pick a name that offends others? Can other people see the name if your Pokémon is in a gym?

Comment: Haha. But I wouldn't name mine the F-word.

Comment: You can try using a funny Trainer name instead, though I'm not sure how they're regulated. My sister's is PenisInMyMouf, which makes me conclude they either do not check or do not care.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Other trainers cannot see nicknames you give Pokemon, so nobody else will be able to tell if you give your Pokemon offensive names.

[Source](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/222049867-Viewing-a-Pok%C3%A9mon-s-Summary-): "...create a personal nickname **that can only be seen by you**" (emphasis mine)

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for and it's probably the easiest solution for the devs to prevent foul language. Thanks!

Comment: You can see the nicknames of Pokémon in gyms, so this answer ought to be amended.

Comment: @jackwise I've never seen another trainer's nicknamed Pokemon in a gym, so I think you only see the nickname in the gym if it's your own Pokemon there.

Comment: @DoktorJ you're correct, I was misremembering. apologies!

Answer (score 0):

They do seem to filter out some things, I couldn't put some names I wanted in there.

Comment: Were the names being censored (i.e., were you trying to enter slurs/swears), or were they just too long? From what I understand, there is a length limit of 11 characters.